# Array sort in worst case w(n) works when first half elements smaller than other half?

Tags: arrays, sorting

This is a theoretical question, so the assumption is that it takes constant time to compare the `elements` in the `array`.

We got an `array` and the first half of its `elments` are smaller than its other half. Nothing is sorted. Will it work to sort it in worst case runtime `O(n)` or there is no way?

I think it will not work, because for sorting the first half it will take `O((n/2)*log(n/2))` time, same for the other half. In total this would be `O(n*log(n/2))` so still `O(n*logn)`?
Is that right or wrong? If possible please explain me.

Answer (score 1):

If that was true, you would have discovered a revolutionary sorting method: to sort N elements, append N dummy elements with a large value, sort in time O(N) and discard the appended elements.

Comment: invoking *tertium non datur* will anger the constructionists :D +1

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: they keep a chance with quantum computing :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, in that case you'd have `n*log(n/2) = n*(log(n) - log(2)) = n*log(n) - n*log(2)` which is in `O(n*log(n))`